# Kubernetes create a persistentVolume per pod in deployment

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have the following `PersistentVolumeClaim` and `Deployment` in Kubernetes:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
     - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
  storageClassName: "gp2"
```

```
...
containers:
   ...
   volumeMounts:
   - name: my-app-storage
     mountPath: /var/my-app/storage
     readOnly: false
   ...
volumes:
  - name: my-app-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-app-storage
```

The problem is this is only creating a single volume that is mounted into each pod. I have `replicas: 3` though. How can I have a volume created per pod? I need to stay using a `Deployment` and can't migrate to using a `StatefulSet`. Is this even possible? Currently, this is scheduling all the pods on one single Kubernetes worker node because the volume is shared and only mounted to a single Kubernetes worker node.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up converting the `Deployment` to a `StatefulSet` and this works. Key thing is remove the `PersistentVolumeClaim` and update the Deployment to a StatefulSet and use the following props:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 16Gi
```